Whats the correct way to nest for VCA (Day, Lot, Operatore)?
I have a data set for a study im working on, i'm usually pretty good with stats but the more I look at this the more I question myself.
So I have a measurement of a analyte taken by two different operators, with two lots of reagents over 4 days, taken in triplicate.
I was using VCA as i need to adhere to CLSI guidlines, and I had seen other examples.
My question is what is the most appropiate nesting for this.
When I do:
anovaVCA(analyte ~ (Lot+Operator)/Day, df)

Which in my head makes sense from a nesting perspective, it produces results that im having a hard time interpreting.
  Name             DF      SS      MS     VC     %Total  SD     CV[%]  
1 total            31.2048                0.7332 100     0.8563 17.3991
2 Lot              1       0.8217  0.8217 0*     0*      0*     0*     
3 Operator         1       1.7927  1.7927 0.028  3.8234  0.1674 3.4021 
4 Lot:Operator:Day 13      14.5582 1.1199 0.2073 28.2789 0.4554 9.2525 
5 error            32      15.9306 0.4978 0.4978 67.8977 0.7056 14.3369

Mean: 4.9214 (N = 48) 


Its obvious from the data that the day is the highest source of variation,  but is this the best way to show this?
